# Why is a sphere necessarily a n-cell glued to a 0-cell?

Tags: homotopy-theory, spherical-geometry, spheres, cw-complexes

I know this is a basic question, but I have not studied homotopy theory yet. What suggested us to define a sphere with one vertex, instead of 0? How does it differ from a monotope then? This is vital in defining the Euler characteristic.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you are thinking about the usual way to write the sphere as a CW complex, the answer is simply that in any CW complex the boundary of any $k$-cell must be collapsed in some way onto a subset of the $(k-1)$-skeleton. In the case of the sphere this makes sense: the sphere is obtained from an $n$-cell by collapsing its boundary to a single point.

Comment: @Mizar I see, it is just based on the definition. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As part of the definition a CW-complex, the boundary of each cell must be contained in the union of all the cells of lower dimension.  This means every nonempty CW-complex must have at least one $0$-cell, since otherwise there would be nowhere for the boundary of the lowest-dimensional cell to go.  (This is not a problem for $0$-cells since they have no boundary.)